# Guardar Valores Tabla en Array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo la siguiente tabla con datos y checkbox, estoy intentado hacer, que cuando selecionen el chekcbok y le den al boton de guardar, se me guarde los datos selecionados con el checkbox en un array y enviarlos por ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<table id="table" class="csstable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <th>head2</th>
        <th>head3</th>
        <th>head4</th>
        <th> head5 </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <<td>test</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="">
        </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
    </table>
   <input type="button" id="guardar" name="guardar" value="guardar">
   </body>
  </html>
```

Aqui tengo mi codigo pero no me guarda nada, no consigo guardar los valores, he probado de otras maneras y tampoco lo he conseguido, no veo como hacerlo.

```
$(document).on('click','#guardar',function(){
                var tdValues=[];
                var columns = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
                var valorcheck=[];


            $('#table input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(e,i){
                if($(this).prop("checked")){
                        console.log(i);
                        valorcheck.push($(this).text());                            
                }
            });

            tdValues.push(valorcheck);
            console.log(tdValues);

            var JSONARRYA= JSON.stringify( tdValues )
                console.log(JSONARRYA);

            });
```

Gracias,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta función:

```
  $('#table input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(e,i){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
      console.log(i);
      valorcheck.push($(this).text());                            
    }
  });
```

Estas haciendo push del texto que contiene el propio input check, que esta vacio.

Prueba cambiando esa linea de la siguiente manera:

```
  $('#table input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(e,i){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
      console.log(i);
      valorcheck.push($(this).closest('tr').children('td:not(:last-child)').text());                          
    }
  });
```

Esto te dara los valores todos juntos, claramente formatealo como sea necesario.

Comment: gracias, ya me guarda los datos,   sobre el formato que me lo guarda que es asi,  0: "test,test,test",  se puede cambiar a 0: "test, 1 test 3 test"

Comment: ya lo tengo, muchas gracias, asi me vale al final.